# microsoft.aspnet.friendlyurls how to remove it

Tags: c#

microsoft.aspnet.friendlyurls been added to a project and no longer need . how to I remove it . I try uninstalling and removing it from the Global.asax
I get the following error

HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

Comment: Open the package manager console, then issue this command 'UnInstall-Package Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls'

Comment: Or try using Nuget to uninstall it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I delete NuGet packages that are not referenced by any project in my solution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012803/how-do-i-delete-nuget-packages-that-are-not-referenced-by-any-project-in-my-solu)