# ServiceBusClient is not present in Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus 7.8.0

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I'm trying to migrate from Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus to Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus

This was the previous implementation

```
final QueueClient sendClient = new QueueClient(new ConnectionStringBuilder(this.queueConnectionString, this.queueName), ReceiveMode.PEEKLOCK);
```

For Migration I'm referring to [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/MigrationGuide.md#approachability) and [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/), which says to make use of ServiceBusClient instead QueueClient, but ServiceBusClient is not present in Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus

What's the fix?

Comment: Try uninstalling and removing existing `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` dlls first and then reinstall it again.

Comment: you can either navigate to **Tools > Nuget Package Manager > Manage NuGet Packages for solution** or use `Uninstall-Package Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` command from your package manager solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reproducing from our end we could able to make this work, However The latest stable version of *Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus* is 7.7.0. If you are using the beta versions of 7.8.0, try using `Install-Package Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus -Version 7.8.0-beta.2` or `Install-Package Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus -Version 7.8.0-beta.1` while installing it. But before try [uninstalling and removing existing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012803/how-do-i-delete-nuget-packages-that-are-not-referenced-by-any-project-in-my-solu) *Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus* dlls first and then reinstall it again.

You can also refer to related samples from [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure/azure-sdk-for-net/azuremessagingservicebus-samples/).

Comment: Wr are actually using Java  and not .NET. What should one do for Java? Delete the jars and reinstall?

Answer (score 1):

For the Java ServiceBus SDK, the migration guide can be found [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/azure-messaging-servicebus/migration-guide.md#sending-messages).
AFAIK, you don't need to delete jars. Just referring to the correct version in the pom file should work.